# Host PHP site on Dropbox

Tags: php, dropbox, synchronization

I use DB on regular basis to host static sites for clients so that it makes easy to change anything and ask to client check. I use 'Public' folder to do that. Colloboration with client becomes super fast and easy.

Now I researched a lot on google on hosting php site there. But didn't found anything. I need to upload small changes to server to show client and the process is again and again.

What you guys recommend as a good solution?

Comment: Sorry, Dropbox doesn't support server-side execution of your PHP scripts. See [this question for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1):

Set up some automatic deployment to a server that your client can access.  Use version control for your changes.  When you merge into a specific branch, your script can automatically do the deployment for you.